# Simulating a click doesn't work... jQuery

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, simulate

I am trying to simulate a click with jQuery if the class of a td is "nee". Somehow all options like trigger, and a document ready click won't work...

HTML:

```
<td align="center" class="one nee">
   <img class="img-swap" src="images/nee.png" alt="Aanwezigheid"/>
</td>
```

Trigger action:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
          $('#some-id').trigger('click'); 
    });
```

The image that the HTML returns is a variable, standard value is "ja.png". But as soon as the item is set to no in the database, the image changes to nee.png. But when that is triggered, I want input fields to appear, the same way as they appear when I click ja.png to change to nee.png. which is with a fade in. separately it works. But I can;t get the click to be simulated.

image changing code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".img-swap").click("click", function() {
            if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
              this.src = this.src.replace("ja","nee");
            } else {
              this.src = this.src.replace("nee","ja");
            }
            $(this).toggleClass("ja");
          });
         });
```

Code for fadein actions:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){       
            $(".nee").trigger("click");
            $("td.one").click("click", function(){
                
                if ($(this).parent().find("td.two, td.three").hasClass("toggled")){
                    $(this).parent().find("td.two").fadeOut(400);
                    $(this).parent().find("td.three").fadeOut(400);
                    $(this).parent().find("td.two").removeClass("toggled");
                    $(this).parent().find("td.three").removeClass("toggled");
                    
                } else {
                    
                    if ($(this).parent().find("td.three").hasClass("DoNotWant")){
                        $(this).parent().find("td.three").fadeOut(400);
                        $(this).parent().find("td.three").toggleClass("DoNotWant");
                    } else {
                        $(this).parent().find("td.three").fadeIn(400);
                        $(this).parent().find("td.three").toggleClass("toggled");
                    }
                    
                    $(this).parent().find("td.two").fadeIn(400);
                    $(this).parent().find("td.two").toggleClass("toggled");
                }                   
            });
            
            $("td.two").click("click", function(){
                
                if ($(this).parent().find("td.three").hasClass("toggled")){
                    $(this).parent().find("td.three").fadeOut(400);
                    $(this).parent().find("td.three").removeClass("toggled");
                    $(this).parent().find("td.three").toggleClass("DoNotWant");
                    
                } else { 
                    $(this).parent().find("td.three").fadeIn(400);
                    $(this).parent().find("td.three").toggleClass("toggled");
                    
                }
            });             
        });
```

Anyone that can help me?

Live example is here:
http://bryan.limewebsolutions.nl/

Comment: You should try chaining. http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/ - I didn't really check this site out completely, but the first blue box seemed to say all that is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) is a shortcut for [`.bind('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), so you don't have to gave the event type (`click`) to the function.

Change your `.click("click", function(){` into `.click(function(){` and your trigger should work properly.

Comment: And this was the correct answer. Thanks to all that helped! I'm a beginner at jQuery, i already found it very exiting that i had written the rest of the code on my own, with little help from Google. But now im satisfied. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SliQz Glad that help you, the answer of Christofer Eliasson contain good advises if you are a beginner in jQuery world.

Comment: @Savetis Thx, That does definately make sense! ill try and have a look at Christofer Eliasson's answer. See what i can do with that one

Answer (score 1):

Instead of triggering a click, I'd say it would be easier to just store a reference to the callback-function, and then use that reference both as your click-event callback and then just call i separately as well, instead of triggering a click event. Something like this:

```
var callback = function(){  
    if ($(this).parent().find("td.two, td.three").hasClass("toggled")){
        $(this).parent().find("td.two").fadeOut(400);
        $(this).parent().find("td.three").fadeOut(400);
        $(this).parent().find("td.two").removeClass("toggled");
        $(this).parent().find("td.three").removeClass("toggled");

    } else {

        if ($(this).parent().find("td.three").hasClass("DoNotWant")){
            $(this).parent().find("td.three").fadeOut(400);
            $(this).parent().find("td.three").toggleClass("DoNotWant");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find("td.three").fadeIn(400);
            $(this).parent().find("td.three").toggleClass("toggled");
        }

        $(this).parent().find("td.two").fadeIn(400);
        $(this).parent().find("td.two").toggleClass("toggled");
    }                   
};

// Bind the click event
$("td.one").click("click", callback);
$(function () {
   // Instead of triggering a click, just call the function
   callback();
});
```

*In this example the callback for `td.two` has been left out for simplicity of the example*

**Side notes:**

1. I believe there is a problem with your logic here, if you have more than one td that match your selector in the if-statement. In that case, the first element that matches will always be used when checking if it has class `toggled`. `.hasClass()` will evaluate the first element in the set of matched elements.
2. You can make your code more efficient by using less DOM-traversing. In the callback, save a reference to the parent in a variable, and use that variable instead of calling `$(this).parent()` every time.

Comment: Hmm, tried it, doesn't give the desired result. The content has to be edited on load, not on a click, if you know what i mean? Page loads with content from the database, so if database says it is no, it loads class no to the div, and in that case, the content behind it should appear..

Comment: @SliQz Okay, so then you have to wait for the DOM to be ready before you call `callback`. Updated my example. (Not sure I understand the last part of your comment).